# Cant create excel sheet with version 2003 using PHP

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying for create excel sheet with the version 2003,using php But i dont get .Wth xlsx extension in my code i dont get excel sheet.I changed the version to xls in my code ,got excel sheet but cant open that file.2003 is installed in system.Any body help me please..

My code i given below.

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
 session_start();

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

 define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli')? PHP_EOL : '<br />');




 require_once("../../../codelibrary/inc/variables.php");
  require_once("../../../codelibrary/inc/functions.php");

 /** Include PHPExcel */
 require_once '../../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

 // Create new PHPExcel object
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->mergeCells('A2:E2');
 $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A2','Sales Register');
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A2')->getAlignment()->
  setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $styleArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true));
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A2')->
  applyFromArray($styleArray);
  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A2:D2")->getFont()->setSize(16);

   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A4', 'Sl No')
        ->setCellValue('B4', 'Date')
        ->setCellValue('C4', 'Ledger Account')
        ->setCellValue('D4', 'Debit Amount')
        ->setCellValue('E4', 'Credit Amount');

   $styleArray = array('font' => array('bold' => true));
                          $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A4')->
   applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('B4')->
   applyFromArray($styleArray);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('C4')->
   applyFromArray($styleArray);
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('D4')->
    applyFromArray($styleArray);
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('E4')->
    applyFromArray($styleArray);

   //ALIGN HEADING TO THE CENTER        
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('A4')->
   getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('B4')->
  getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('C4')->
  getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
  $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('D4')->g
  etAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
   $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getStyle('E4')->
   getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

  //FOR SETTING WIDTH OF EACH COLUMN
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(5);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(15);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(20);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('D')->setWidth(15);
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(15);

   $sl_no=1;
   $r=5;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer";
  $qry = mysql_query($sql);
 if(mysql_num_rows($qry)>0)
  {
    while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry))
    { 
       $cell1 = 'A'.$r; 
       $cell2 = 'B'.$r; 
       $cell3 = 'C'.$r; 
        $cell4 = 'D'.$r; 
       $cell5 = 'E'.$r; 

        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell1,$sl_no); 
         $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell2,$res['name']); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell3,$res['address']); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell4,$res['email']); 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($cell5,$res['supp_id']); 

        $sl_no++;
        $r++;
     }
   }

  / /Redirect output to a client's web browser (Excel2007)
  header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-
  officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Sales Register.xlsx"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

  $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel2007');
  $objWriter->save('php://output');
 exit;          
 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried saving the file to disk and open it? If this works your headers are wrong. If it does not your PHPExcel part is wrong. Would help identifiying the broken part

Comment: no,i dot tried for ave to disk..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a standard install, MS Excel 2003 reads and writes `BIFF-format` files (`.xls` extension), though there is an optional "compatibility toolkit" plug-in that also allows it to read/write `OfficeOpenXML-format` files (`.xlsx` extension).

PHPExcel's `Excel5` Writer creates `BIFF-format` files; the `Excel2007` Writer creates `OfficeOpenXML-format` files.

If you're generating output for MS Excel 2003, then you should use the `Excel5` Writer, unless you know that the "compatibility toolkit" plug-in has been installed for the MS Excel 2003 users who you're creating the files for

Comment: gave xls extension,at the the time cant open the file,shows the message file is not in recognizable form.

Comment: Are you using the Excel5 Writer as well as a .xls extension?

Comment: Open the generated file in a text editor and look for leading/trailing whitespace characters, a UTF-8 BOM header, any plaintext PHP error messages in the file, any HTML markup in the file, etc.... if error messages, then you'll need to deal with those errors; anything of the others and your code is injecting that into the filestream causing the file to be corrupted